# Upload or create new file with content via Google Drive REST API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a new document based on a template through the Google Drive REST API (I'm not using the Java or JS SDKs).

I'd like to create the document based on a word-processing template, either by downloading the template from Drive and replacing some content $keywords, or, editing an rtf format template and inserting that as a new file.

I'm comfortable with REST and I'm able to download the template from Drive, and access the exportLinks to download the file content as rtf or txt.  But... once I've edited the content, how to I provide that content as fileContent to the insert/update http post?

Is this possible? I thought it would be through the method:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at this documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads You can use simple media upload or multipart upload each of which are well documented in the link above.

FYI, if you already have a file and you just want to replace the data of it, you would also want to take a look at [Files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update). The way you upload is same as the documentation above.