# Upload local files to Drive programmatically

Tags: google-drive-api

What I need to do is to upload to Google Drive an XLS file that I have in my laptop drive.

C:\Users\my user\Documents\HC_201603.xls

But I need to upload it programmatically, and I think I could perform this with Drive API, but certainly I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help in this issue

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. You'll need to do some research and attempt your own solution first. Then as you hit specific problems, look for the answer here, or ask a new question.

Comment: What have you done so far? have you tried reading this docs? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads. Found this SO tickets related to Google Drive API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317638/inserting-file-to-google-drive-through-api / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199804/upload-or-create-new-file-with-content-via-google-drive-rest-api

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll review those docs.

Comment: What have you done so far? have you tried reading this docs? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads. Found this SO tickets related to Google Drive API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317638/inserting-file-to-google-drive-through-api / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199804/upload-or-create-new-file-with-content-via-google-drive-rest-api